# TFSPreview build server can't build NUnit test project due to missing 'NUnit' namespace

Tags: azure, nunit, tfsbuild

The setup: 
TFSPreview.com (MS Team Fortress in Cloud) for

- code repository
- build server (manual build trigger, auto-deployed to Azure cloud service)

VS 2012 Solution

1. WCF service project
2. test WCF service project (NUnit based)
3. Azure Cloud project (only covers #1 above)

Problem: 
Build fails because `stats.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

stats.cs line #7 is 
`using NUnit.Framework;`

the nunit .dll is at `<test project>\lib\nunit.framework.dll` and in solution explorer when I go to the test project -> references -> nunit.framework -> properties, `Copy Local` is already `true` (so it should manually copy over the .dll to azure for deployment)

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! This was a super simple fix. Although it was compiling locally it wasn't compiling on the build/TFS server because the `<test project>\lib\` folder wasn't checked into TFS !! So the `Copy Local` = `true` didn't matter since it's a deployment stage setting and we're failing earlier at the compile stage itself! Posting back incase it helps someone else ...